# How to fix [ux-field]?

Tags: discussion

I see [ux-field](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-field) misused far more often than it's used correctly. The goal of the tag, as described in its usage guidance:

> Questions relating to the general UX field, such as career, academic aspects, its relation to other fields and disciplines, and other topics that relate to the field as a whole.

The description is clear, but instead, we have a random assortment of questions that have been mistagged (go ahead and browse them if you'd like).

Obviously we shouldn't be surprised that people don't read the descriptions for each tag they add, but I think another issue is that the term "field" is too ambiguous.

- Forms have *fields*
- Research has "*field* studies"
- Jobs exist within a particular *field*
- My neighborhood park has *fields*

**Proposal:** If we rename this to "ux-profession" or "ux-career", this might help to reduce the amount of abuse this tag gets, as those terms are less up for interpretation. I understand that "profession" or "career" is more focused than "field", so perhaps "ux-work" or "ux-discipline" would more broadly cover the same reach while also reducing ambiguity?

I've also found the [ux-designer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-designer) tag. Its usage is described as:

> Concerns and thoughts about being a UX Designer. This is an abstract tag. It may not directly be linked to a specific problem. It caters to being a UX designer and the career aspects of it.

This seems highly related, but still perhaps slightly more limited in scope than [ux-field](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-field).

Perhaps there are other solutions I've not yet reached.

Comment: Should I go ahead and do a cleanup on this tag myself? Not sure how tag cleanups normally go... Obviously, that would bump a lot of questions to the front page, which might not be ideal. How should I proceed?

Comment: Agreed. The tag is named in a way that people misuse it thinking it's about form fields. Also, given the description of the ux-field tag, how many of such questions would actually end up being non-discussion-based?

Comment: Could I get a moderator's input on this?

Answer (score -1):

> **How to fix [ux-field]?**
>
> I see ux-field misused far more often than it's used correctly.
>
> The description is clear, but ...
>
> Obviously we shouldn't be surprised that people don't read the descriptions for each tag they add, but I think another issue is that the term "field" is too ambiguous.
>
> Proposal: If we rename this to ...
>
> Perhaps there are other solutions I've not yet reached.
>
> How should I proceed.

I suggest:

Check out some of the wisdom offered on the Main Meta and ours:

- [Improve description of tag wikis in Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322558/improve-description-of-tag-wikis-in-help-center), and his [guidance offered here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/322557/282094).
- Look at related guidance, such as [burninate-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/burninate-request), [tag splitting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107914/splitting-a-tag), and [merging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/merging).
- Read the Main Meta FAQ titled: "[How do I correctly tag my questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions)", and the general FAQ's section [Tagging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/282094).
- Read our question: "[Are there PhD topics for user experience?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/8645/are-there-phd-topics-for-user-experience?rq=1)", see what constitutes the scope of the field. Know what *really* should be on topic for the tag and ensure that the Wiki is correct.
- Check out [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=bump&room=89) chat and see what people say about bumping, see what people do to avoid the impact and how the effort is perceived by the community. Read a thread about a recent [tag merge request](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7476365#7476365) and that Mods can merge without bumping, and a year old [thread about retagging](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6818748#6818748). It looks like a new tag can be created, using [tag synonyms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag-synonyms) or merging and a Moderator can simply rename; which swaps everything over without bumping. If you must bump on a busy site doing 10 per day will get them moved off the main page rather quickly, on a site with low traffic you'll flood the first page and not be popular.

How to cleanup:

1. Check the tag's definition in the "[Learn more](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tags/ux-field/info)" on main. Also refer to the "[Excerpt History](https://ux.stackexchange.com/posts/9067/revisions)".
2. Search on our [Meta](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-field) (**0** results) and our [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=ux-field&room=389) (52 messages) for discussions.
3. Read the first few dozen [entries on the last page](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ux-field?sort=newest&page=8&pagesize=50) of the ux-field tag (when sorted by newest, since sorted by oldest isn't an option). Check ***why*** the tag was created in the first place and if there has been reasonable drift in the definition over time. The history shows any refinements.

   Determine how often 'tagging without looking' has spoiled that effort and determine how much work lies ahead. (Hint: There are 391 questions tagged, if 1/3 are bad that's ~130, if only 10% are bad that's ~40 that will need retagging).

   If there's a ton of work determine if you need something like [Burnaki](https://stackapps.com/questions/7027/burnaki-tracking-progress-and-helping-burnination-efforts-on-stack-exchange).

   You can use this question and our chat to recruit some help.
4. Write this question (done) and fill in any blanks/update occasionally.
5. Once a course of action is decided on you can get started.